# pycharm on host machine, file ONLY on guest/remote machine

Tags: vagrant, pycharm, remote-server

Is it possible to use pycharm installed on the host machine, to use remote interpreter and files on a vagrant guest machine, without having a copy of them on the host machine?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you have to pay the licencse to do it. yYou'll need to use Pycharm Professional Edition

See [pycharm info](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/)